# How to change dynamically attachment file name in django CSV export?

Tags: python, django, csv

I Added static file name manju.csv but I want assign variable to filename like today date.
Please help me

```
def district_wise_download(request):
    from_date = request.GET.get('from_date')
    to_date = request.GET.get('to_date')
    district = request.GET.get('district')
    print(district)
    if 'district' in request.GET:

        new_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        new_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        min_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(new_from, datetime.time.min)
        max_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(new_to, datetime.time.max)

        download_district = All_enquiries.objects.filter(Q(enquired_at__range = (min_dt, max_dt))&Q(district=district))

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] =  'attachment; filename="manju.csv"'

        writer =  csv.writer(response, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['created_at','product_name','product_category','price','customer_name','customer_mobile','state','district','city','pincode','status','remarks','source','username'])

        for obj in download_district:
           writer.writerow([obj.enquired_at,obj.product_name,obj.product_category,obj.price,obj.customer_name,obj.customer_mobile,obj.state,obj.district,obj.city,obj.pincode,obj.status,obj.remarks,obj.get_source_display(),obj.user_id])

        return response
```

Comment: this question was answered quite often, please google the next time. first import datetime on the top of your file add the `format` function here then `response['Content-Disposition'] =  'attachment; filename="manju_{}.csv".format(datetime.date.today())"`

Comment: great thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `date` module from `datetime`.

```
from datetime import date
def district_wise_download(request):
    from_date = request.GET.get('from_date')
    to_date = request.GET.get('to_date')
    district = request.GET.get('district')
    print(district)
    if 'district' in request.GET:

        new_from = datetime.datetime.strptime(from_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        new_to = datetime.datetime.strptime(to_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
        min_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(new_from, datetime.time.min)
        max_dt = datetime.datetime.combine(new_to, datetime.time.max)

        download_district = All_enquiries.objects.filter(Q(enquired_at__range = (min_dt, max_dt))&Q(district=district))

        response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="manju_{}.csv"'.format(date.today())

        writer =  csv.writer(response, delimiter=',')
        writer.writerow(['created_at','product_name','product_category','price','customer_name','customer_mobile','state','district','city','pincode','status','remarks','source','username'])

        for obj in download_district:
           writer.writerow([obj.enquired_at,obj.product_name,obj.product_category,obj.price,obj.customer_name,obj.customer_mobile,obj.state,obj.district,obj.city,obj.pincode,obj.status,obj.remarks,obj.get_source_display(),obj.user_id])

        return response
```